# FRP-style GUIs in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I recently built a small web application using riotjs, a library that facilitates creating UIs in the spirit of functional reactive programming, i.e. defining the UI as a pure function of the application's state, much like the far better known reactjs.

Or so I was told, I think. I'm still not sure if I grasp the concept of FRP correctly.

Now I got to thinking. Is there anything to gain by writing UIs in Java in a similar way? That is, writing functions that take the state as argument and returning the updated GUI elements. Because what I've seen so far in terms of Java GUI development didn't feel like that. Or maybe some framework or industry quasi-standard already does GUIs in a FRP-way and I simply haven't recognized it as such yet.

Or more generally: **What is the state of FRP-style GUI development in Java?**

Comment: `What is the state of FRP-style GUI development in Java?` -- Seems solid.  See https://realm.io/news/droidcon-gomez-functional-reactive-programming/

Comment: @robert-harvey, great link! In general, Java isn't very much friendly to immutable-state-addicts. But there are some frameworks (not specifically GUI, though) that can help. ReactiveX for Java from Microsoft and Netflix is one example. Not FRP by formal definition, but it seems to me, that's what you ask for. SoduimFRP is another. Also, there is a book from Manning: Functional Reactive Programming by Stephen Blackheath and Anthony Jones.

Answer (score 1):

Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) is indeed a programming paradigm that has gained popularity in recent years, especially in the context of web development with libraries like ReactJS and RiotJS. The core idea is to treat the user interface as a function of the application's state, where changes in the state automatically reflect in the UI.
In Java, the adoption of FRP principles for GUI development has been somewhat different due to the language's history and ecosystem. Traditionally, Java GUI development has been dominated by imperative frameworks like Swing or JavaFX, where the UI is manipulated through direct method calls and event listeners. However, there are efforts and libraries that bring FRP concepts into the Java world. Like,

**ReactFX**: This library is an attempt to bring reactive programming to JavaFX. It allows developers to build user interfaces in a way that's more declarative and functional, similar to React in JavaScript.

**RxJava**: While not specifically a GUI framework, RxJava is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences. It's often used in combination with Java GUI frameworks to create a more FRP-like experience.

**Bindings and Properties in JavaFX**: JavaFX itself has features like bindings and properties that allow for a more reactive style of UI development. While not purely FRP, they allow for a declarative style of programming where the UI can automatically update in response to state changes.

**TornadoFX**: Although it's a Kotlin-based framework, TornadoFX is worth mentioning. It's built on top of JavaFX and offers a more declarative way of building UIs, which can be appealing to those looking for FRP-style development in the JVM ecosystem.

While Java's GUI development hasn't been historically aligned with FRP principles, there are libraries and frameworks that enable a more reactive, state-driven approach to UI development. The trend seems to be slowly shifting towards adopting these paradigms, particularly in newer and more modern frameworks. However, it's also important to consider the learning curve and the specific requirements of your project when choosing an approach.